# Will ARIMAX or exponential smoothing forecast a short time series better?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, exponential-smoothing

The objective requires to predict GROSS NPA for 6 months and provided with 2 years of data i.e., around 24 observations. So, which of the method will provide better forecast?

Comment: You can't know for sure, you should try both out and see which one works better.

Comment: Can you please clarify what NPA is, in this context? Thank you.

Comment: Also, what regressors are you using for ARIMAX?

Comment: We are having principal outstanding distributed in 31 buckets for each month where 0th bucket to 1st bucket  means the customer will default by 30 days.Here after 6th bucket customer tend to default more. Gross NPA here is the sum of the principal outstanding from 6th bucket to 31st  bucket. This gross npa is considered as the dependent variable and the principal outstanding for each buckets are considered as the independent variable. But the problem here is that the no.of parameters are more than the no.of observations.hence we proceeded with arima and exponential smoothing time series model.

Comment: But if we want to use arimax model how can we go ahead with this data?

Comment: Hi: check out the koyck distributed lag. There's simple way to estimate it and it requires just one regressor. The error term can vary also. There's tons of literature on it and it may be relevant for what you're doing. If you can't find anything good, let me know and I'll dig up my saved literature on it. It's somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to know which will give better forecasts, as it largely dependent on the data, noise level, etc. There is a solid article discussing this very problem (including exponential smooth vs ARIMA on short series) here:

http://robjhyndman.com/papers/shortseasonal.pdf

Answer (score 0):

That depends on multiple factors, as previously mentioned: noise and parameterization could be the crux of the question.

Reading some articles in a general approach you can confirm that arima is more useful to short term forecasts, but at the end always all depends on your data...